# Django formset with manytomany through intermediate model

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to save data to an intermediary model and do some calculations in the model (by overriding model save). The problem I have is with formsets not able to save to the intermediary model.

The intermediary model is created only when there is M2M relationship (that's understood I guess).

I have 4 models like so:

```
Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(..)

Tax(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(..)
   rate = models.DecimalField(..)

CategoryItem(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    taxes = models.ManyToManyField(Tax, through='CategoryItemTax', through_fields=('item', 'tax'))
    quantity = models.DecimalField(..)
    price = models.DecimalField(..)

# intermediary model below
CategoryItemTax(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    tax = models.ForeignKey(Tax)
    item = models.ForeignKey(CategoryItem)
    rate = models.DecimalField(..) #derived from tax object in the model
    total_tax = models.DecimalField(..) #calculated in model save
```

My I have a Category model form with CategoryItem formset. My views.py as below:

```
class FormsetMixin(object):
    object = None

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if getattr(self, 'is_update_view', False):
            self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        formset_class = self.get_formset_class()
        formset = self.get_formset(formset_class)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, formset)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, formset)

    # THE SAVE METHOD
    def form_valid(self, form, formset):
        self.object = form.save()
        formset.instance = self.object
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for i in instances:
            CategoryItemTax.objects.create(category=self.object, item=i, tax=i)
            CategoryItemTax.save()

class CategoryCreateView(FormsetMixin, CreateView):
    template_name='..'
    model = Category
    form_class = CategoryForm
    formset_class = CategoryItemFormSet
```

Forms.py as below

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Category

class CategoryItemForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = CategoryItem

CategoryItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Category, CategoryItem, form=CategoryItemForm, extra=1)
```

Unfortunately I get the below error:

```
Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.
Use category.CategoryItemTax's Manager instead
```

Comment: Could you show the formset?

Comment: I have added the forms.py code.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your view like this,

```
def form_valid(self, form, formset):
    self.object = form.save()
    formset.instance = self.object
    instances = formset.save(commit=False) 
    for each in instances:
        each.category = self.object
        each.save()
        item = CategoryItemTax.objects.create(category=self.object, item=each)
        item.save()
```

Many to many related objects must be saved first inorder to associate with another instance.

Comment: `Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use category.CategoryItemTax's Manager instead.` - this is the error that keeps showing up.

Comment: You need to understand that, there is no Tax object is created in this view. Inorder to create a many to many relationship, Tax objects as well as CategoryItem object is needed. If you would explain what you are trying to accomplish here, maybe I could be of much more help

Comment: it's a simple invoicing application, and you can add multiple taxes to each categoryitem (line-item).

Comment: In this view tax objects are not created, then how the many to many field can be added, then/

Comment: That's exactly what I've been thinking, but I don't have an idea to approach this.

Comment: I think you need to change your formset.... change the `CategoryItem` in formset to `Tax` then create `CategoryItem` objects from `formset.instances`..